# tkinter Right widget changable on press button

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-layout

Hi create a GUI with tkinter where on left side i have all button and right all page.. every button on left call a page on right..
everytime that i click button pack right frame but i want create only one to show only one page, so i try to destroy previously but when i try to destroy right frame i get

```
    right.destroy()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'right' referenced before assignment

    def mapview():

    righthome.destroy()
    right.destroy()

    right=Frame(mainFrame, padx=20, pady=20)
    right.pack(fill="both",side=LEFT,padx=(0,20), expand=True)
    #right.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="nswe",padx=10)
    right.columnconfigure(1,weight=3)
    right.configure(bg="#353434")

    '''
    canvas=Canvas(right)
    canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)
    canvas.columnconfigure(0, weight=2)
    canvas.configure(bg="gray")
    '''
    map_widget = TkinterMapView(right, width=600, height=500, corner_radius=0)
    map_widget.pack(fill="both",expand=True)
    #map_widget.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)
    #map_widget.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    containerbottom=Frame(right)
    containerbottom.pack(fill="x")
    #containerbottom.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="we")
    containerbottom.configure(bg="#353434")

    entertext=Entry(containerbottom)
    entertext.pack(side="left",ipadx=25,ipady=5,pady=(20,0),padx=80)
    #entertext.grid(row=0,column=0)
    entertext.configure(bg="#1C1C1C")

    btn=Button(containerbottom, text="search", relief="flat",padx=50,bg="#1686C5",fg="white",font="Ubuntu 13")
    btn.pack(side="right",pady=(20,0),padx=80)
    #btn.grid(row=0,column=1, pady=10)



# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# MAIN 
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

root= Tk()
root.geometry("1000x700")
root.configure(bg="red")
root.title("Windows test app")

mainFrame=Frame(root, bg="#2A2A2A",padx=50,pady=50) # bg="#2A2A2A"
mainFrame.pack(fill="both",expand=True)
mainFrame.configure()

left=Frame(mainFrame, padx=40, pady=20)
left.pack(fill="y",side=LEFT, padx=20)
#left.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nswe",ipadx=20,padx=10)
left.configure(bg="#353434")
left.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

cmd_tr=Button(left, text="cmd on trains",bg="#1686C5",fg="white",font="Ubuntu 13", relief="flat", state="disable")
cmd_tr.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="we",pady=(20,5))

cmd_scr=Button(left, text="cmd on 19\" screens",bg="#1686C5",fg="white",font="Ubuntu 13", relief="flat", state="disable")
cmd_scr.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="we",pady=10)

movieplay=Button(left, text="Lunch a movie",bg="#1686C5",fg="white",font="Ubuntu 13", relief="flat", state="disable")
movieplay.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="we",pady=10)

sim_cards=Button(left, text="Swap sim cards",bg="#1686C5",fg="white",font="Ubuntu 13", relief="flat", state="disable")
sim_cards.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky="we",pady=10)

ap_agv_page=Button(left, text="AGV AP check",bg="#1686C5",fg="white",font="Ubuntu 13", relief="flat",command=pag2)
ap_agv_page.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky="we",pady=10)

ap_evo=Button(left, text="EVO Aps check",bg="#1686C5",fg="white",font="Ubuntu 13", relief="flat", state="disable")
ap_evo.grid(row=5,column=0,sticky="we",pady=10)

map_page=Button(left, text="Train Localizator",bg="#1686C5",fg="white",font="Ubuntu 13", relief="flat",command=mapview)
map_page.grid(row=6,column=0,sticky="we",pady=10)

exitbtn=Button(left, text="Exit",bg="#F1444C",fg="white",font="Ubuntu 13", relief="flat",command=root.quit)
exitbtn.grid(row=7,column=0,sticky="we",pady=50)


righthome=Frame(mainFrame, padx=20, pady=20)
righthome.pack(fill="both",side=LEFT,padx=(0,20), expand=True)
#righthome.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="nswe",padx=10)
righthome.columnconfigure(1,weight=3)
righthome.configure(bg="#353434")


canvas=Canvas(righthome)
canvas.pack(fill="both",expand=True)
#canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)
canvas.columnconfigure(0, weight=2)
canvas.configure(bg="#353434")


maintitle=Label(canvas, text="Nola Service Desk",bg="#353434",fg="#F1444C",font="Ubuntu 16")

    maintitle.pack(side=TOP, pady=15)
    maintitle.configure(
            bg="#353434",
            fg="#C51F5D",#fg o foreground per il colore del testo
            font="Ubuntu 30 bold"
            )
```

Tried also to use an if statement to check if right.winfo_exists() useless..
can someone help me.. thank you

Comment: You need to tell Python that `right` is a global variable by adding `global right` inside `mapview()` function.

Comment: Actually there is no `right` defined in global when `mapview()` is first executed.  I think you need to change `right` to `righthome` instead inside `mapview()` and add `global righthome`.